# JQuery delegate what may cause it to not function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a webpage using jquery 1.42

The following 2 segments of code live in my page.

```
$('body').delegate('h2', 'click', function() {
    $(this).after("<p>delegate paragraph!<\/p>");
});

$('body h2').live('click', function() {
    $(this).after("<p>live paragraph!<\/p>");
});
```

The live method always works, yet the delegate doesn't fire at all.

If I create a trivial page with simple html

```
<body><h2>blah</h2></body>
```

both approaches work.  So I'm assuming there is something else going on in my page.

With firebug I am seeing no javascript errors, no html errors. and breakpoints on the delegate method definately do not get hit.

What else might be the cause of delegate not triggering?

EDIT: heres the list of other scripts on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2010.1.416/telerik.common.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2010.1.416/telerik.textbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2010.1.416/telerik.grid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2010.1.416/telerik.grid.filtering.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2010.1.416/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/2010.1.416/telerik.grid.editing.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/akeyo/2/edit  works fine for me.

Comment: My problem is delegate isn't working.  I wish to use .delegate() over .live()  but I cannot get delegate to trigger in a non trivial page. So is there anything else that may cause jquery delegate to stop functioning is ultimately my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as the toolset I was using, Telerik ASP.NET MVC controls 2010.1.416 had a reference to jquery.validate.min.js

The version of the file they ship is 1.5.5

Updating this version to 1.7  and delegate is again working as expected.

/smack.

Comment: don't forget to mark this as the correct answer. Good work on finding the fix.